# Synchronized Autowired bean not working in server but working in local eclipse

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a Synchronized Spring bean like below :

```
 public class AbstractMDPConfiguration{    

protected static Map<String,RjpResProcessor<ErrResponse>> myConfig;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("myConfig")
protected synchronized void setMyConfig(Map<String,RjpResProcessor<ErrResponse>> myConfig){
this.myConfig=myConfig;
}

}

 public MyClass extends AbstractMDPConfiguration{

 public static getSomeConfig{
  //inside this method myConfig is coming as null
 }
```

The myConfig bean is null in the getSomeConfig method while running junits in jenkins server.
But when i am running the same code in my local eclipse(both junit and actual code) it is working fine.
When the same junit is running in server,the myConfig is null.

Comment: Can we see the failing unit test please? (whole class)

Comment: The junit is not calling the class directly,our framework invokes the getSomeConfig() method internally as part of the flow.

Comment: Can you try adding a log statement inside setMyConfig method ? To verify if the setter method is called or not.